# How can I select a common mode choke for DC/DC power conversion stages

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design, low-pass, switching-regulator, common-mode-choke

I want to attenuate 15 MHz noise signal using a common mode choke at 5 V power lines stage of a circuit that generate digital signals with less than 100Mhz.

[image: 5V-3V3 conversion circuit]

When you use a common mode choke for a power conversion stage  between 5 V power lines and the regulator that converts 5 V to 3.3 V, you want to make a kind of low pass filter, allowing only DC signal into the regulator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fouygX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't actually know how to calculate the choke main values. I haven't faced this challenge before.
I have also read that even a choke can filter correctly your noise, it could generate undesired high voltage transients if the choke selection is not well done.

I spent a significant time searching the way for choosing a proper choke parameters for applications like this.
I also have often seen circuits that implements common mode choke filtering in different parts of their circuits. In ex CAN bus or, as said before, power lines, etc.

I know current is an important parameter for choke model selection. This must be upper than nominal current of the real circuit in the worst case operation. If I want to attenuate a 15 MHz with this inductor [744273501](https://www.we-online.com/components/products/datasheet/744273501.pdf) for common noise in a power stage:

1. How should I use impedance and inductance datasheet specifications?
   [image: choke main parameters]
2. How should I read or should I translate its impedance curve into the desired attenuation at 15 MHz frequency?
   [image]
3. Could I use other choke model with different L value if the curve shows the frequency attenuation that I need?
4. Is there any quick expression to calculate the relation between cut frequency, L value and the Z values from the Zcm(f) curve for checking if the model fits?
5. Could it been said that (attenuation at 15Mhz) **A(f=15Mhz) = Z(f=15Mhz)/RLoad** as a quick approach?
6. Where should it be placed on a PCB for a better effectiveness?

Comment: You should really ask the new designers to justify the case for adding a CM choke and, you realistically need to say what the problem was i.e. how it manifested as a problem for the circuit in your question. Getting the frequency of the noise right (not guessing) is fundamentally important.

Comment: Noise at 15kHz and  at 15Mhz is a big difference.

Comment: Why do you think you need a CM choke when your problem states a DM problem? The CM choke will still pass differential-mode noise. It seems like what your suggesting is the wrong solution to your problem.

Comment: Common mode means current flowing between grounds, between cables, external connections. To choose a CM choke, we must know the impedance it is embedded within. Thus we need to know what all connects to the unit, both the immediate connection itself (is it a battery on a lead? power supply connected to mains or earth? long cable? what else does it connect to? etc.), and *unrelated connections* (are there signal or power cables to other devices? how many, how long? do they connect to anything else in turn? etc.).

Comment: @MOSFET it is a design that solves a noise situation with a 15Mhz that any low pass filtering was not able to attenuate netiher cause any effect on the noise signal. External engineering says that it was a common voltage noise. So they put a choke on this circuit and noise stopped the interference on this circuit. I have no way to talk with them because the work relation stopped time ago.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams any suggestion for how to calculate the impedance of the whole of circuit connected to the chocke output? perhaps this circuit voltage divided by the total current consumption?

Comment: @Andyaka it is not an option. Other way I would done it yet

Comment: @TimWilliams 5V power leads comes from a meanwell power bank. Leads could vary depends on the set installation. 25cm-50cms is the range. Noise came from other devices connected to the AC plugs of the same room where the power bank was connected. Inductive loads based (rotor machine and another relay based machine). The PCB implements Rs485 bus to comunicate with microcontroller uart, some spi (a gpio expander) and 2ci xips (rtc, lcd screen).

Comment: Could you add a diagram illustrating that information? Also, what power bank is it? What wires are in the cables (signals/functions), and what type (mainly, are the cables shielded or not)?